# How can I display my data in the admin from many to many field in django?

Tags: django, django-admin, many-to-many

I need some help with the many to many in the django admin.
My values saved in the team models are not being displayed in my member section. The dropdown list is empty, and in my team model admin, data are only displayed in the filter section but not on the main list. 
Here are my models:

```
DEPARTMENT = (

    ('C', 'Children'),
    ('C', 'Choir'),
    ('C', 'Cleaning'),

)
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(choices=DEPARTMENT, max_length=10)
    member = models.ManyToManyField('Member', related_name='team')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Team'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Member(models.Model):
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    names = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDER, max_length=1)
    dob = models.DateField()
    contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=14, help_text="+27740000000")
    email = models.EmailField(help_text='your email address')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="you street, number, complex name only")
    suburb = models.CharField(max_length=20, help_text="your suburb")
    area_code = models.IntegerField(help_text="0000")
    province = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PROVINCE)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text="Your daily occupation")
    registered_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.surname
```

and in the admin:

```
class TeamInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Team.member.through
    extra = 1


@admin.register(Member)
class MemberAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('surname', 'names', 'email', 'contact_number', 'suburb')
    fieldsets = (
        ('Member personal details', {
            'classes': ('grp-collapse grp-open',),
            'fields': ('surname', 'names', 'gender', 'dob', 'contact_number', 'email',
                       'address', 'suburb', 'area_code', 'province', 'occupation', 'registered_date',
                       ),
    }),
    )
    list_filter = ['surname', 'email', 'suburb']
    inlines = [MaritalInline, TeamInline, MembershipInline,]


@admin.register(Team)
class TeamAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name',)
    fieldsets = (
        ('Team details', {
            'fields': ('name',),
    }),
    )
    list_filter = ['name', ]
    inlines = [TeamInline, ]
```

and here are my screenshot:

- [in adding member section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nq0CP.png)
- [in the team model admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7afW.png)

Comment: How is it the `DEPARTMENT` choices all have the same value?

Comment: what do you mean the same value?

Comment: `choices` is a list of tuples `(value, verbose_name)`, all your values are `'C'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inlines are for related relationships, not many-to-many. You must use a form field. Default is `<select multiple>` which is not very appealing, but you can make it sexier with [select2](http://select2.github.io/) for instance (see also [django-autocomplete-light](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/) to ease select2 integration with Django) or [create a custom field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/fields/#creating-custom-fields) or [widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/widgets/).

Comment: thank you but how can you use the select2 in the admin?? and also is this line in teaminline correct  model = Team.member.through?? or should I completely remove the teaminline. and do you mind being more explicit on how to get it work? thanks @AntoinePinsard

Comment: Everything you need is in the links I pointed, there is no single solution. It's up to you to read the docs. And this question was asked like I don't know how many times: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=django+admin+many-to-many+widget